# How to allow any user on the server to edit a specific file?

Tags: linux, perl, permissions, sudo

I have created this code which will allow user to change the port in a specific file,

```
#Change Port
IRSSIPORT1=`head -n 1 /etc/ports.txt | tail -n 1`
sudo perl -pi -e "s/^$IRSSIPORT1.*\n$//g" /etc/ports.txt
sudo perl -pi -e "s/web_port = 8081/web_port = $IRSSIPORT1/g" .sickbread/config.ini
echo "sickbread Port: $IRSSIPORT1" | sudo tee -a $HOME/private/SBinfo.txt
```

What this code do is it takes a number from a file and then put it in the config file where it is required to change and deletes that number from the initial file from where it took it, but it requires read access as well as write access,

I tried everything in my knowledge to get it work without sudo, but i failed to do it.

Any suggestion?

I get this error -

> Can't remove /etc/ports.txt: Permission denied, skipping file.

Comment: This is the error "Can't remove /etc/ports.txt: Permission denied, skipping file."

Comment: This feels like an xy problem. You are asking about perl when your problem is permissions.

Comment: Yes, I am aware that its about Permission, not really sure how to fix it :/

Comment: tried both, i cannot set sudo as i require all user to use it as for chmod i tried 777 still not working.

Comment: This question might be more suited for `superuser.com` or `unix.stackexchange.com`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do inplace edit on `666` files inside `/etc` as `-i` switch makes new file and deletes old one inside directory.

Since users don't have sufficient permissions to add/delete files from `/etc` (nor it would be good idea to do so), you have to read all file content at once, change it, and write back to the same file. Using a temporary file is also a workable solution.

Comment: For minimum effort on your behalf, you can make a symlink in /etc to some directory/file where your users have sufficient permissions, ie. `ln -s /some_folder/ports.txt /etc/`

Comment: It still wont work, i tried /ports.txt, i tried /var/ports.txt still the same error Can't remove /var/ports.txt: Permission denied, skipping file.

Comment: @Harsh first make sure that your users can write to directory. I highly doubt that `/` and `/var` are one of them.

Comment: THANKS A TON ^_^...That worked out great created new folder named /port and chmod it 777

Answer (score 0):

While it may seem that the question is more about system administration rather than about programming, it's actually somewhat about perl so it's may be a good place for it here.

Doing `chmod 666 /etc/ports.txt` grants all users read-write access to this particular file (of course you don't need to put 777 as it's not an executable or script). So anyone will be able to open this file for writing and put any contents in it.

But when you do `perl -pi -e ... /etc/ports.txt` you don't only write into that file. Instead, perl will want to delete and then recreate this file, as shown here in `strace` output:

```
# strace perl -pi -e 's/a/b/' /etc/ports.txt 2>&1 | grep /etc/ports.txt
...
open("/etc/ports.txt", O_RDONLY)        = 3
unlink("/etc/ports.txt")                = 0
open("/etc/ports.txt", O_WRONLY|O_CREAT|O_EXCL, 0600) = 4
```

To delete the file it will need to have a write access not to the file itself, but to the directory `/etc`, which of course you cannot give to any user.

So I suppose you just don't need to try using in-place edit as it's always related to removing or renaming files, but instead get the contents of the file, make required changes and then write it back to the same file.

Comment: It still wont work, i tried /ports.txt, i tried /var/ports.txt still the same error Can't remove /var/ports.txt: Permission denied, skipping file. also i require this because it is fully automatted script and it is a small part of it which i required to run without sudo or root

Comment: You missed the point about directory permissions. Your script should work without changes if you use, e.g., `/var/tmp/ports.txt` as everyone has write access to `/var/tmp`. But if you want to use a non-777 directory, change your script to avoid in-place edit (`perl -i`).